# Reports in Google Data Studio without manually running R

Tags: python, r, powerbi, looker-studio

I have data running from a server to Google BigQuery. I would like the data to be analysed in R or Python and have the results presented in Google Data Studio or have resulting tables returned to BigQuery. I've read about the packages `bigrquery` and `googleCloudStorageR`, but I don't want to manually run the scripts through R studio every time new data is pushed to the server.

Is there a way to have a R/Python script connected to BigQuery which runs every time new data is pushed to BigQuery. I read this is possible in Power BI, but can't find a solution for Google Data Studio. Summarising; I would like a dashboard with live (or frequently updated) data that needs some analysis in R/Python, but without running the code constantly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible via the [googleCloudRunner package](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudRunner/), which lets you set up pub/sub messages that can be triggered from BigQuery table updates, to run R code then push to another BigQuery table. Its one of the example use cases on the website.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising! In the meanwhile I've used Heroku to schedule my scripts.